# Who are the voice actors for the player characters and followers?

Tags: diablo-iii

[IMDb lists](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2186735/fullcredits#cast) some of the voice actors and their parts—including the very recognizable [Wizard Princess Azula](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0217221/) and [Malcolm Reed the Templar](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0444098/)—but only has the Wizards, and female Demon Hunter and Witch Doctor actors.

Who did the voice acting for each of the 10 player characters and 3 followers?  Bonus points for mentioning how they might be commonly known (other Blizzard games, TV series regular, etc.)

Comment: And as an addendum - who's voicing Leah?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It just so happens that all of the main cast is listed under the Credits button. I've written them down below for reference, including a link to their IMDB page where available. The vast majority of them have voice acted for other big games, including Star Wars: The Old Republic and Mass Effect 3.

#### Player Characters

- Barbarian - Female: [Athena Karkanis](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1920701/)
- Barbarian - Male: [Dorian Harewood](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0002126/)
- Demon Hunter - Female: [Anna Graves](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0336247/)
- Demon Hunter - Male: [Robin Atkin-Downes](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0235960/)
- Monk - Female: [Rajia Baroudi](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0056431/)
- Monk - Male: [Jamieson Price](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0528936/)
- Witch Doctor - Female: [Erica Luttrell](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0527518/)
- Witch Doctor - Male: [Carl Lumbly](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0525855/)
- Wizard - Female: [Grey Delisle](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0217221/)
- Wizard - Male: [Crispin Freeman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0293342/)

#### Leading Cast

- Adria: [Alyson Reed](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0715295/)
- Deckard Cain: [Michael Gough](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0299855/)
- Leah: [Jennifer Hale](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0354937/)
- Tyrael: [Jonathan Adams](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1201149/)

#### Followers

- Enchantress: [Sumalee Montano](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0599019/)
- Scoundrel: [Troy Baker](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1684869/)
- Templar: [Dominic Keating](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0444098/)
- Blacksmith: [Simon Templeman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0854742/)
- Jeweler: [James Hong](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0393222/)
- Mystic: [Gaille Heidemann](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1085573/)

#### Additional Characters

- Abd al-Hazir: [Brian George](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0313364/)
- Ashera: [Courtenay Taylor](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1057696/)
- Auriel: [Cree Summer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0838588/)
- Azmodan: [David Sobolov](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0811875/)
- Belial: [Jim Ward](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0911616/)
- Captain Hale: [Lloyd Sherr](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1204201/)
- Captain Rumford: [Greg Ellis](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0254862/)
- Emperor Hakan: [Sofia Pirri](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm5061536/)
- Imperius: [Rick Wasserman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1484330/)
- Ithereal: [James Horan](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0394533/)
- King Leoric / Skeleton King: [Joe J. Thomas](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1741007/)
- Maghda: [Susanne Blakeslee](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0086840/)
- Mistress of Pain: [Claudia Black](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0085227/)
- Zoltun Kulle: [Steve Blum](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0089710/)

Furthermore, there are a ton of people credited for "Additional Voices" and "Monster Voice Effects".

EDIT: In the interest of providing a source for this, I've added a screenshot of the first part of the credits as well.

[image: Credits from Diablo III]

[image: Credits from Diablo III]

Comment: Athena Karkanis is neither listed in the screengrab there nor in the IMDb credits. I'm pretty sure the female barbarian is voiced by [Helena Charbila](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2167959/).

Comment: @RKumar: It's not in the screenshot because not that much text fits on the screen (she's the first voice credit given), and I didn't see the point of uploading an image when it didn't add any information (I can't upload it right now either, because I don't have Diablo 3 on this computer). Athena Karkanis not being listed on IMDb is simply because no one added that credit: most of these weren't listed when I wrote this post.