# Who was the voice actor of the pilot in the Descent Freespace intro cinematic?

Tags: descent-freespace-1

Recently rewatched the intro cinematic for Descent Freespace (aka Freespace 1):

I'm just blown away by the pilot's acting. I Googled around but couldn't find the actor's name. [Game's credits](https://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/descent-freespace-the-great-war/credits) don't list them either. Anyone know?

Comment: Post received a downvote but not sure why. Please let me know if these types of questions are frowned upon here. I figured it would be OK based on other questions like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341256/who-is-the-voice-actor-for-vlad-in-magicka), [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67130/who-are-the-voice-actors-for-the-player-characters-and-followers), and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94383/who-are-the-far-cry-3-voice-actors).

Comment: I think this is a valid question +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this question will be nearly impossible to answer.

In the 90s voice acting was mostly done in house, professional voice actors (or actors) were a rarity only used in few games. Volition was a branch of Parallax (the descent devs) and Freespace was their first game as an independent company. It's unlikely, they employed known voice actors for their first effort.

The [Imdb page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0169922/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) only lists three known voice actors, two of which had Freespace as their only project in this timeframe and the third, Valerie Milenka Repnau, doing several voice acting jobs in video games. But since she is a woman, we can rule her out as Lt. ashs voice actor. The two men had bigger roles in the game and are also unlikely to be Lt. Ash. As Ash only exists for the intro movie, it's most likely that one of the developers served as his voice actor. A clue to this is, that one of VAs on imdb is [Duncan McPherson](https://www.mobygames.com/developer/sheet/view/developerId,7504/), who worked as a developer at Volition in the late 90s. So even a fairly big role like the training instructor was filled with a dev.

There are no sources out there, which can confirm who lent this character his voice and this makes the question impossible to answer, the best we have is that it is one the following people: Rick Barrows, Phil Strang, Jeffrey Coleman, Mark Allender, Dan Kuhlman or Jeremy Barnal (the males listed on the synchronization cast on your mobygames link minus the two we can eliminate).

Your best bet to get a definitive answer would be to contact Volition directly and ask them. Though I wouldn't bet on them knowing who voiced an intro character in a 21 year old game, but possibly they've documented it and can find the files.

Comment: Thanks for the info, especially the bit about companies rarely employing professional voice actors at that time. Marking as accepted for now. I'm going to see about contacting Volition and/or cyber-tracking down some of the original team members to ask. Will add an answer here if I find anything.